# Return an array from PHP to erlang

Tags: php, http, erlang, erl

I'm trying to return an array of two values from PHP to erlang. I'm making a http call from erlang to a web server using

```
http:request.
```

The web server is returning the array as

```
 $args = array($p1, $p2);
 return $args;
```

On Erlang side I receive as

```
  {ok, {_,_,Body}}
```

I'm trying to log what I receive, and that seems a little weird. How can I cleanly pass an array to erlang.

**Note:** when I do is_list(Body) in erlang, that returns true.

Comment: When you say the web server returns the array, are you sure that you don't need to *output* the contents in a structured way, i.e. JSON or XML format?

Comment: missing $$$$$$$$$$$$$$

Comment: editing per @Dagon

Comment: return works quite differently  depending on context, it that's your whole php script. you wont get anything: http://ideone.com/YwZC7p